Preparing or cooking the food?
When you want to ask someone to see whether he/she cooked a food or not, which one should be used?

Did you prepare it yourself?
Did you cook it yourself?


The two words have different definitions:

Preparing food would include chopping it, mixing it etc. You might 'prepare' a salad, but salads are not usually cooked!

Cooking generally refers specifically to the process of using heat to change the food's state. You can buy some foods ready-prepared so there is no preparation; all you do is cook them.


However, in general everyday use you might find English speakers use one word or the other to mean both. If you've ever seen the TV show The Great British Bake Off they begin the competition by saying "ready, set, bake!", and the contestants start preparing, mixing, kneading etc, long before any actual 'baking' (a specific kind of cooking process) begins. So, if someone says they are going to begin "cooking", that may well include all the preparation stages.
Also worth noting, in favour of them being interchangeable, is that "meal prep" (short for 'preparation') is an increasingly popular term that refers to preparing and sometimes cooking meals long before you eat them, and that the same process is called "batch cooking" by some.

But I didn't get my answer, You want to ask if someone made food, How do you say it?

@Daniel Hi Daniel - welcome to the site. I'm sure you read the site rules before you posted so you'll know that asking "is this correct" is off-topic. I thought your question was a bit deeper than that, but if the answer you're looking for is "this one is right, the other is wrong" then perhaps I'm mistaken about its suitability. If you read my answer again what I'm telling you is that they are both okay in general contexts when you're not trying to distinguish between the different stages of creating a meal, but in other contexts you may need to use one or the other.

"You want to ask if someone made food." Well "Did you make it yourself?" is perfectly idiomatic.

@KateBunting Thanks a lot Kate! I learned something.
